# How to split a string into multiple different variables in batch

Tags: batch-file

So I am working on a project and I am trying to pull each line from a text file and split each one of them up and give different parts of them different variables. For example, with one of my strings here (below), I want to make 12 set to the variable "output[1]_x" and I want 10 to be set to "output[1]_y". I also want to split "sf2" and "a" into other variables as well.

`12,10:sf2/a;`

Here is the code for what I have already tried.

test.bat

```
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type test.txt') do (
    Set /a cell+=1
    Set "output[!cell!]=%%a"
    set "output[cur]=%%a"

    echo !output[cur]!
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%i in ("!output[%cell%]!") do set output[%cell%]_x=%%i
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%i in ("!output[%cell%]!") do set output[%cell%]_y=%%i

    echo !output[%cell%]_y! >> _TEMP.txt

    call:findString output[%cell%]_y "," pos

    if not defined pos echo.Substring not found&goto:eof
    echo.Position is: %pos%
    set /A pos=%pos%+1


    echo x: !output[%cell%]_x!
    echo y: !output[%cell%]_y:~%pos%,2!
    echo.
)

pause





REM https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=194 credits DosItHelp
:findString -- returns the zero based postion of one string in another string of maximum length of 1023 characters
::          -- %~1: in - varible name of a string to be serached
::          -- %~1: in - string to be found
::          -- %~3: out- return variable name, will be set to position or undefined if string not found
set "str=!%~1!"
set "str=!str:%~2=@@@@!
set "str=%str:@@@@="&REM %
if "%str%"=="!%~1!" (
   ENDLOCAL&IF "%~3" NEQ "" SET "%~3="
   GOTO:EOF
)
set str=A!str!&  rem keep the A up front to ensures we get the length and not the upper bond
                 rem it also avoids trouble in case of empty string
set len=0
set /a n=1024
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
set /a n^>^>=1, len+=n
 if !str:~%len%!. == . set /a len-=n
( ENDLOCAL & REM RETURN VALUES
    IF "%~3" NEQ "" SET %~3=%len%
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Also here is test.txt

```
0,0:sf2/a;
12,10:sf2/a;
7,16:sf2/a;
9,4:sf2/a;
```

If you would like me to explain or elaborate on anything, just let me know and I will do so.

Thanks,
Exro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you overcomplicated a bit:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=,:/;" %%a in (test.txt) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "output[!count!]_x=%%a"
  set "output[!count!]_y=%%b"
  set "output[!count!]_z1=%%c"
  set "output[!count!]_z2=%%d"
)
set output
```

Comment: I just checked if I got the right outputs and it works perfectly! Thank you so much. Have a wonderful rest of your day.